# pagination ,sorting, grouping, and Export to excel IN WPF data-grid

Tags: .net, wpf, sorting, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I looking to perform pagination ,sorting, grouping, and Export to excel IN WPF data-grid.
I am using devexpress wpf control.

Kindly advise me if i can get some demo.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're exactly asking but take a look at the following points at [DevExpress.Com](http://www.devexpress.com):

- [WPF Grid Control Overview](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/)
- [WPF Grid Control ClickOnce Demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/DemoCenter/WPF/?GridDemo/)
- [WPF Grid Control Documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6084)

Official and guarantied assistance: [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create)